# DropDownListFor method instead of property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Is it possible to use a method in stead of a property for an

This works:

```
HTML.DropDownListFor(x => x.Book, 
                     new SelectList(ViewBag.Books, 
                                    "ID", 
                                    "Title", 
                                    new { @class = "form-control"}))
```

that I tested does not:

```
HTML.DropDownListFor(x => x.Book, 
                     new SelectList(ViewBag.Books, 
                                    "ID", 
                                    "ToString()", 
                                    new { @class = "form-control"}))
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: can you explain the usecase for this? in what scenario you need that?

Comment: Well I am doing some selfstudy on the front-end part of ASP.net and it was just something I came across. I am a back-end developer but I was wondering about if such things are possible. If it is, I can use it in some designs for example names of people.

Comment: The simple answer is no. For more details check the documentation of `SelectList` class constructor

Comment: I have read the documentation but sometimes people here know a workaround. That's why I wondered if anyone knew a way for that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a workaround for it.
For anyone who is interested in it this is what works:

book.cs

```
public class Book
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Booktitle")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Voornaam")]
    public string AuthorFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tussenvoegsel")]
    public string AuthorLastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return CompleteName(); }
    }

    private string CompleteName()
    {
        return this.AuthorFirstName + " " + this.AuthorLastName; 
    }
}
```

View.cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Book, new SelectList(ViewBag.Books, "ID", "FullName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: workaround for what ?!! .. your answer doesn't replated to your question .. you bind it to property like MSDN said and all answered to you ... your question was can I bind it to method ??

Comment: Well you can return the method with a property. Then you can use the method in the DropDownListFor.

Comment: No you cann't use Method, you can only use property "FullName" .. what you did not a workaround, it is a property assign

Answer (score 1):

No you cann't pass a function, If you back to SelectList MSDN documentation, you won't find any override for it take function.

[SelectList MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: This is more a comment.

Comment: more a comment ?! what is that mean ?

Comment: I mean this should be a comment link answer are not good enough. You should at least put some quotes from this link location.

Comment: according to question, he asked a simple question "can I pass a function", the answer is No and I've included the msdn link .. no need for quotes .. msdn link is a good reference